# username and password should be the same to delete a record

Tags: android

I,m developing a sqlite based CRUD app.my create and Read is ok. But if I want to delete a record, the user name and the password for the record should be the same.If not, the Delete function do not work. For example:" if the user name is 123, the password should also be 123".If not the delete function jumps to the else statement in the code...

Here is the code

public class Delete extends Activity {

```
Button buttonDelete,buttonUpdate;
EditText textDelete ;
TextView logTxt;


DBConnector DBConnector;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.delete);

    // get Instance  of Database Adapter
    DBConnector =new DBConnector(this);
    DBConnector = DBConnector.open();

    // Get Refferences of Views
    textDelete=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtDelete);
    logTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.log);


    buttonDelete=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnDelete);
    buttonUpdate = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnUpdate);
    buttonDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {


            String userName=textDelete.getText().toString();


            String storedName= DBConnector.SelectedEntry(userName);


            if(userName.equals(storedName))
            {
                DBConnector.deleteValues(userName);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "record deleted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent Main=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(Main);
            }


            else
            {

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No such a user name exists ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Intent Main=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(Main);





            }
        }
    });
    buttonUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent update=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Update.class);
            startActivity(update);

        }
    });
    logTxt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent log=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Log.class);
            startActivity(log);

        }
    });

}
```

}

Comment: `DELETE FROM table WHERE password='1234', username='johndoe'`

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How to overcome this issue?